# Android - Referring to onListItemClick within onDialogPositiveClick?

Tags: android, adt

Is it possible to refer to onListItemClick within onDialogPositiveClick? Can I literally put onListItemClick in onDialogPositiveClick, or do I have to do something completely different? Here is my code...thanks for all/any help!

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements TheDialog.NoticeDialogListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] sites = {"Google", "Amazon", "Ebay" , "Reddit", "SmashingMag", "CCC"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist_item, R.id.textView1, sites);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TheDialog();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Confirm");
    Intent i = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 1:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 2:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ebay.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 3:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.reddit.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 4:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.smashingmag.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 5:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.myccc.corning-cc.edu"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog `TheDialog` will be shown only *after* `onListItemClick` already completed and handled the selection according to your `switch` logic.

Therefore you won't need to call it again after dialog is dismissed. I generally would recommend against calling `onListItemClick` directly.

Moreover, as you startActivity with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in `onListItemClick`, your dialog will likely be hidden by a browser window till you come back to your activity.

I guess you just want your dialog to act as confirmation before you open Url based on clicked list item. You can achieve this with simple changes to your code :

- declare member intent in activity : `Intent mActionViewIntent;`
- change `switch cases` to :

```
case 0:
    mActionViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    break; // note not sending intent here
case 1:
    mActionViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
    break; 

// ..etc
```

- Then start activity with the `mActionViewIntent` if user confirms it with dialog :

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    startActivity(mActionViewIntent); // start web-browser
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! Do you happen to have any tips on how I can make it so the onListItemClick will not commence until after the onDialogPositiveClick completes?

Comment: @webhoodlum since you create your dialog in `onListItemClick` it will always compelete before dialog is created, as both `onListItemClick` and `onDialogPositiveClick` run on the same UI thread. I think you want something different : in `onListItemClick` you create intent with speicific URI, then pass this to your dialog, annd when dialog completes with "OK" button, it will open URL from intent passed to it(dialog).

Comment: You dont even need to pass intent to dialog if you make it member variable. I added code to my answer, hope that helps